# How can i add css class to zoomIn and zoomOut buttons? Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I have two css class "mapzoom-in" and "mapzoom-out" for zoom in and zoom out controls
But I do not know how to add classes to the buttons
Does anyone have an idea?

I want  get element by this code:
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#domutil

```
get(<String|HTMLElement> id)
```

But for example  this is zoomIn button html content.But the button does not have a specific id

```
<a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+<div></div></a>
```

and then use addClass and add my class to zoom in control

I try

```
var zoomInBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-zoom-in")[0].className="mapzoom-in";
var zoomOutBtn =document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-zoom-out")[0].className="mapzoom-out";
```

work but they hide

Comment: You want to take a reference to the button. Why to add class? You can use the built-in classes What style do you want to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You just want to get a reference to the `HTMLElement`s for each button, and you thought about adding a CSS class to each as a solution; then you're asking about problems implementing your attempted solution, rather than asking about what you want to achieve.

You can get a reference to each of the `HTMLElement`s for the zoom buttons by pairing Leaflet's [`getContainer()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#control-getcontainer) method for [`L.Control.Zoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#control-zoom) together with [the `querySelector()` method of any `HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), e.g.:

```
var leafletMap = L.map('map-container');
var control = leafletMap.zoomControl;
var controlElement = control.getContainer();
var zoomInElement = controlElement.querySelector('.leaflet-control-zoom-in');
var zoomOutElement = controlElement.querySelector('.leaflet-control-zoom-out');
```

Also, if you only have one zoom control per map, you can use [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) to get the appropriate `HTMLElement`s via `querySelector`, e.g.:

```
var zoomInElement = document.querySelector('#map-container .leaflet-control-zoom-in');
```

There is no need for IDs or CSS classes for individual buttons.